# IBM MobileFirst Platform Operations Console : No runtime can be found

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

My setup:

- MobileFirst Platform foundation 6.3.0.00-20141127-1357
- WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0 (1.0.3.20130510-0831) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.7.0_75-b13 (en_US)
- hosted on softlayer

Installed using the knowledge center guide for 6.3.
I have 1 issues now that I can't seem to understand:

Built the .war and tried to deploy it using the server config tool but I end up with "no runtime found" like in the various posts.

Things I have checked:

- my java version that was fine
- checked the entries in server.xml for duplicates of WL Admin services war, only one exists.
- checked that server config tool actually deploys war file in servers/servername/apps and updates server.xml
- tried setting run and deploy settings in eclipse to point to my server

What else can I check? Going a little nuts now. did this installation a few months back and I don't remember struggling this much.

logs: http://pastebin.com/Z6CwqCVV
server.xml: http://pastebin.com/MnpjQ2GY

Also, does anyone know of a good write up explaining the manual deployment method, tried the ibm docs but they seem to assume I know more than I do.

Would like to understand the core elements I need to update in the server xml and where to move the various wars, to manually configure mfp after install.

Comment: Line 50 of your log, you have a report of an FFDC incident FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/worklight/common/i18n/MessageCatalog com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated 1341" at ffdc_15.03.30_04.27.06.0.log.  Can you have a look at the file ffdc_15.03.30_04.27.06.0.log in 'serverdir'/logs/ffdc ? It may include valuable information about the root cause of the problem.

Comment: It seems I don't have those logs anymore, I'll go through the manual deployment pages, but I'd imagine the server config tool would be less error prone?

Comment: Yes - that's the goal of the server config tool. Automate to avoid human errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would like to understand the core elements I need to update in the server xml and where to move the various wars, to manually configure mfp after install.

The manual instructions are here:

1) For the Worklight Console (and administration service)

- Databases (mySQL): https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_config_MySQL_DB_manually_for_wladmin.html (includes declaration of datasources in the application server)
- Application Server (WAR files / jndi variables / features / appserver configuration...)  https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_liberty_profile_for_wladmin_manually.html

Then you have similar instructions for the runtime (Project WAR file built with the Worklight Studio or CLI)

For the database of a runtime (with mySQL) : https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_config_MySQL_DB_manually.html [Includes steps to declare the datasource to Liberty]

For the Liberty Server: (features / library / war file etc..)
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/c_manually_configuring_app_server.html

The Server Configuration Tool should do the same.

Comment: so found a copy of 6.3 to build the apps and worklight console is available and I can deploy adapters but not wlapps. Checked similar posts that point to max_allowed_packet - but not the case for me changed both inis restarted with --default ini. and checked show variables

Comment: I have this error:
     
E internalRun() Exception <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Object "com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-com.ibm.worklight.dataacc‌​ess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-1" is not managed by this context. FailedObject: com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-com.ibm.worklight.dataacce‌​ss.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-1. What does not managed by this context mean? where can I learn these errors? –

Comment: mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';

| max_allowed_packet | 524288000 |

Answer (score 1):

NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException exceptions are emitted when you start the Liberty server meaning generally that you worklight-jee-library.jar file is not present in the ${shared.resource.dir}/worklight/lib directory or is not the right one. Another possibility is also that your runtime is not migrated to 6.3 and is not in phase with the 6.3.0.00-20141127-1357 version.

Note also that Liberty 8.5.5.0 is not supported : http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1404132386734&osPlatforms=AIX|Linux|Mac%20OS|Mobile%20OS|Solaris|Windows&duComponentIds=S003&mandatoryCapIds=1|13|132|72&optionalCapIds=30|7|12|130|9|1|132|141|19|16|4|26

Minimum version for MFP 6.3 is Liberty Profile 8.5.5.3.

Comment: Liberty Profile 8.5.0.2 is supported as well. But the versions 8.5.5.[012] are not supported.

Comment: So wiped the server, switched to Liberty profile 8.5.5.4, re-installed mfp 6.3 and I am still getting the class def errors. Checked that I have worklight-jee-library.jar in my shared.resource.dir. So what else can I check? logs : http://pastebin.com/H3V9dkhf  I still have no runtime when I deploy. Is there a clearer manual deployment guide? The ibm docs seem to assume an understanding of the mfp components that is beyond me

Comment: How to you install the WAR file ? Do you copy a WAR file built by the Studio, or did the Server Configuration Tool install it ? (The server configuration tool performs a migrate operation to make sure the WAR file is binary compatible with the worklight-jee-library)

Comment: Tried copying it, I could have missed a setting in the server.xml though, so will try that again, but would like to understand bit more. In fact was looking for a good write up on what configs to manually edit when copying the WAR file. Otherwise I mostly used the server config tool

Comment: Anthony, I asked because if you didn't use the server config tool but copied it you may have skipped a step if your development environment is not in the same version as the server and that may explain the class not found error you have. This step is documented here, but you don't need to know about it if you use the Server Configuration Tool (it's automatically performed in that case)  https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devenv/r_migrating_old_wl_project_to_new_wl_server.html

Comment: Yes I used the server config tool the majority of the time. Also it was a very basic setup, installed liberty core, created a server, installed mfp, then started a server, then created a config, restart the server and then add a runtime. I am not sure where I could break something since I am just using the installation manager and the config tool...

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace in your new log file http://pastebin.com/H3V9dkhf indicates that you are using a worklight-jee-library.jar from a MobileFirst Platform version 6.3 or earlier, in combination with a project WAR file that

- either comes from MobileFirst Platform (Studio or MFP CLI) version 7.0,
- or comes from an older MobileFirst Platform but was migrated to version 7.0 (possibly through use of the Server Configuration Tool / Ant tasks from MobileFirst Platform 7.0).

This combination is not supported, according to the table 2 in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_compat.html.

You need to

- either upgrade your server to 7.0,
- or use the Server Configuration Tool / Ant tasks from a version that matches your server.

Comment: understood, when you say use server config tool that matches your server you mean server config tool from MFP 6.3 for apps built with 6.3 and sever config tool from mfp 7 if building with mfp 7 right?

Comment: The server config tool and the ant tasks migrate automatically a runtime war if this war was not built with the same Studio version than the MFP server version. It means that if you have for example installed MFP 7.0 you can with these tools deploy a runtime built with Studio 6.3, 6.2.... Without migration your 6.2/6.3 war is incompatible with MFP 7.0. But you can never deploy a runtime built with a Studio version more recent than your MFP server. So for example a runtime built with Studio 7.0 cannot run in a MFP Server 6.3