# MFP 6.3 console wlapp upload just displays deploying

Tags: websphere-liberty, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

MobileFirst Platform foundation 6.3.0.00-20141127-1357
WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0 (1.0.3.20130510-0831) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.7.0_75-b13 (en_US)
hosted on softlayer
Project WAR version: 6.3.0.00.20150214-1702

Follow up on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341829/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-operations-console-no-runtime-can-be-found/29384701#29384701)

Was unable to to deploy a runtime because I was using a different MFP-WASLP server version. Able to do so now. However can't deploy -wlapps.

I got a "Is not managed by this context" error, could that be referring to the MFP context? Found a few posts on here but they all point to max_allowed_packet. I was able to set my.ini files and confirm with show variables. so I don't think that's it.

I get the following error:

```
[4/6/15 7:24:55:845 CEST] 000000fc com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction              E internalRun() Exception
<openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Object "com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-1" is not managed by this context.
FailedObject: com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-1
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.processArgument(EntityManagerImpl.java:1216)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.processArgument(BrokerImpl.java:2149)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.gatherCascadeRefresh(BrokerImpl.java:2816)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.refresh(BrokerImpl.java:2793)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.refresh(DelegatingBroker.java:1078)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.refresh(EntityManagerImpl.java:688)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.setNewProjectTransactionID(BaseTransaction.java:618)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.internalRun(BaseTransaction.java:315)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction$1.run(BaseTransaction.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Just curious, although I doubt it, is there an error reference anywhere?(I could use that instead of always asking on so).

P.S my project war version and MFP are bot 6.3 but slight different versions(couldn't be the issue right?):

```
MobileFirst Platform foundation 6.3.0.00-20141127-1357
Project WAR version: 6.3.0.00.20150214-1702
```

Comment: Since you mention contexts... What is the context of your runtime (it should be usually the MFP project name)? Are you deploy wlapps generated in said project? Can you test w/out Softlayer and see if the issue repeats itself?

Comment: The runtime and the project have the same name, will test locally and report back, many thanks. Might just be build and deploy settings on eclipse. Just in case I might have missed something is there anything else I can check with the max_allowed_packet

Comment: This does not seem related to max_allowed_packet.

Comment: Must say that this sounds related to Softlayer.

Comment: I am not sure how to go about troubleshooting this now- rebuilt the app double checked the context, redeployed the war still get the same error. Will try it on AWS but would like to be able to narrow down the error

Comment: Btw what is the "project entity-1" that the error refers to?

Comment: lol ok, checking starting from scratch. Dotting the i's and crossing the t's

Comment: Anthony K, it would be best to write answers rather than comments.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out something was up with the DB, reproduced the issue by adding mfp server, adding a config, adding a runtime, removing them and trying to add new ones or renamed ones failed to deploy. Was able to deploy the apps when removed runtimes, configs, dropped the db tables and deleted the mfp server folder in usr/servers/servernameFolder. After that had no issues whatsoever. Thank you for helping sort out the initial mfp-liberty srv mismatches. And all the links to manual config helped me understand MFP better –